# Is AirPlay at attack vector into a private network?

Tags: wifi

Our software dev team has an Apple TV and we want to have it connected to the corporate network to be able to reach internal resources while testing custom apps.

Our ops team does not want it connected to that network (they only want it on the guest network) because we have AirPlay turned on (deliberately so guest presenters can share their screen) and therefore the AppleTV becomes a bridge to the internal network.

Is this possible, likely and preventable?

Comment: Can't you just switch the configuration when guest presenters come?  For example: normally, the TV would be connected to the corporate network with AirPlay disabled.  When a guest presenter comes, disconnect the TV from any network and just enable AirPlay.  After they leave, switch it back.  Why won't that work, or am I missing something?

Comment: It'll work, it's just a PITA.

Comment: Understood.  I am not very familiar with AirPlay, so I won't write an answer, but here's my take on it.  If somebody is smart enough, they can probably find a way to use AirPlay as a bridge to get into your corporate network.  HOWEVER - they would have to be within about 100m of the TV in order to exploit this (WiFi range +  good antenna).  So as long as the TV isn't somewhere exposed like in the lobby area, you should be able to be reasonably sure that nobody with that skill set will come close enough to the TV for long enough and happen to be searching for that specific vulnerability.